# React and Typescript: How to extend generic component props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, react-component

Imagine a flexible component that takes a `React.ComponentType` and its `props` and renders it:

```js
type Props<C> = {
  component: React.ComponentType<C>;
  componentProps: C;
  otherProp: string;
};

const MyComponent = <C extends {}>(props: Props<C>) => {
  return React.createElement(props.component, props.componentProps);
};
```

Can I somehow let `MyComponent` receive the dynamic `props` directly, e.g. like that (not working):

```js
type Props<C> = {
  component: React.ComponentType<C>;
  otherProp: string;
};

const MyComponent = <C extends {}>(props: Props<C> & C) => {
  const { otherProp, component, ...componentProps } = props;
  return React.createElement(component, componentProps);
};
```

Error:

```
Error:(11, 41) TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'Pick<Props<C> & C, Exclude<keyof C, "component" | "otherProp">>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes & C'.
      Type 'Pick<Props<C> & C, Exclude<keyof C, "component" | "otherProp">>' is not assignable to type 'C'.
        'Pick<Props<C> & C, Exclude<keyof C, "component" | "otherProp">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'C', but 'C' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here we need to understand some utility types and how the destructuring happens in TS.

```js
type Obj = {
  [key: string]: any
}

interface I1 {
  a: number
  b: number
  c: number
}

const i1: I1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1,
}

let {a, ...rest} = i1

interface Obj {
    [key: string]: any
}

const i2: Obj & I1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1,
  c: 1,
  d: 1,
  e: 1,
}

let {a: a1, b, c, ...rest2} = i2

function func<T extends Obj>(param: I1 & T) {
    const {a, b, c, ...rest} = param
}
```

In the above code, the inferred type for `rest` will be `{b: number, c: number}` because object `i1` contains only three keys and one of them aka `a` is exhausted. In the case of `rest2`, TS can still infer type to `Obj` as keys from interface `I1` are exhausted. By exhausted I mean they are not captured using rest operator.

But in case of function, TS is not able to do this type of inference. I don't know the reason why TS is not able to do. That may be due to limitation generics.

What happens in case of a function is that the type for `rest` inside the function is `Pick<I1 & T, Exclude<keyof T, "a" | "b" | "c">>`. `Exclude` excludes keys `a`, `b` and `c` from the generic type `T`. Check Exclude [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion). Then, `Pick` creates a new type from `I1 & T` with keys returned by `Exclude`. Since `T` can be any type, TS is not able to determine the keys after exclusion and hence the picked keys and hence the newly created type even though T is constrained to `Obj`. That's why the type variable `rest` in the function remains `Pick<I1 & T, Exclude<keyof T, "a" | "b" | "c">>`.

Please note that type returned by `Pick` is a subtype of `Obj`

Now coming to the question, the same situation happens with `componentProps`. The type inferred will be `Pick<Props<C> & C, Exclude<keyof C, "otherProp" | "component">>`. TS will not be able to narrow it down. Looking at the signature of `React.createElement`

```js
 function createElement<P extends {}>(
        type: ComponentType<P> | string,
        props?: Attributes & P | null,
        ...children: ReactNode[]): ReactElement<P>
```

And calling it

```js
React.createElement(component, componentProps)
```

The inferred type for `P` in the signature will be `C` in your code from the first argument i.e. `component` because it has type `React.ComponentType<C>`. The second argument should be either `undefined` or `null` or `C` (ignoring `Attributes` as of now). But the type of `componentProps` is `Pick<Props<C> & C, Exclude<keyof C, "otherProp" | "component">>`, which is definitely assignable to `{}` but not to `C` because it is subtype of `{}` not of `C`. `C` is also a subtype of `{}` but the pick type and `C` may or may not be compatible (this is same as - there is a class A; B and C derives A, objects of B and C are assignable to A, but object of B is not ascribable to C). That's why the error

```
        'Pick<Props<C> & C, Exclude<keyof C, "component" | "otherProp">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'C', but 'C' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

As we are more intelligent than TS compiler, we know that they are compatible but TS does not. So make TS believe that we are doing correct, we can do a type assertion like this

```js
type Props<C> = {
  component: React.ComponentType<C>;
  otherProp: string;
};

const MyComponent = <C extends {}>(props: Props<C> & C) => {
  const { otherProp, component, ...componentProps } = props;
  return React.createElement(component, componentProps as unknown as C);
  // ------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
};
```

This is definitely a correct type assertion because we know that type of `componentProps` will be `C`

Hope this answers your question and solves your problem.